# Nuxt is retuning a api mapping in a forign language [Invidious]

Tags: json, typescript, nuxt.js, mapping, nuxtjs3

so I am using the indivious api and for some reason it is returning this

```
publishedText   "9 ساعات منذ"
```

even when the api returns

```
publishedText   "9 hours ago"
```

this is how the api mappings are handled

```
function formatViewCount(viewCount: number) {
  if (viewCount >= 1000000000) {
    return `${(viewCount / 1000000000).toFixed(1)}B`;
  }
  if (viewCount >= 1000000) {
    return `${(viewCount / 1000000).toFixed(1)}M`;
  }
  if (viewCount >= 1000) {
    return `${(viewCount / 1000).toFixed(1)}K`;
  }
  return viewCount.toString();
}

function formatDuration(lengthSeconds: number) {
  const minutes = Math.floor(lengthSeconds / 60);
  const seconds = lengthSeconds % 60;
  const duration = `${minutes}:${seconds < 10 ? '0' : ''}${seconds}`;
  return duration;
}

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://inv.tux.pizza/api/v1/popular');
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Something went wrong');
    }
    const data = await response.json();



    const thumbnail = ((video: any) => {
      const sddefaultThumbnail = video.videoThumbnails.find((thumbnail: { quality: string; }) => thumbnail.quality === 'sddefault');
      const sddefaultUrl = sddefaultThumbnail.url;
      return sddefaultUrl;
    });


    return data.map((item: any) => ({
      
      title: item.title,
      author: item.author,
      thumbnail: thumbnail(item),
      time: item.publishedText, 
      views: formatViewCount(item.viewCount),
      duration: formatDuration(item.lengthSeconds),
    }));


  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      data: JSON.stringify({ error: 'Something went wrong' }),

    };
  }
});
```

idk what to try and it is expected to return the json data in english like the api url I'm fetching the data from